# How to display both sides for a coded mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, show, mesh

I handcoded a swirl model in Unity and now it can only display one side of the model, for the inside side you cannot see it, what should I do? Do I need to make another mesh and use opposite normals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off [backface culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-CullAndDepth.html) in your shader.